# Simplify $\lim\limits_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{a}+1}$

Tags: limits

Suppose $f(x)=\lim\limits_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{a}+1}.$

How can we simplify $f(x)$?

Here's a graph of $\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{a}+1}$ as $a$ approaches $0$:

[image: Graph Animation]

Intuitively, I would think that $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
because every point on the graph becomes arbitrarily close to zero except at $x=0$.

Mathematica, on the other hand, seems to give conflicting answers:

```
f[x_]:=Limit[1/(x^2/a+1),a->0];
Element[s,{0}];
f[s]
f[0]
```

produces

```
0
1
```

even when $s$ in the code above is constrained to the set $\{0\}$.  Mathematica's answer seems to depend on whether $x$ was substituted before or after simplifying the limit, but that doesn't seem like correct math to me.

So does $f(0)=0$ or $1$?

Comment: For $x=1$ function is not defined, and for $x=0$ it is $-1$.

Comment: Do you want $a\to 0$ or $a\to1?$ $a\to1$ is easy…

Comment: But you write: “Here’s a graph of $\lim_{a\to1}\dots$ as $a$ approaches $0.$” Which is meaningless.

Comment: In any event, for any $a\neq 0,$ $f_a(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}a-1}$ has $f_a(0)=-1,$ so I’m not sure how you’re graph works. It seems to have $f_a(0)=1.$

Comment: I think the OP's problem is $\lim _{a \to 0} \frac{1}{{\frac{{x^2 }}{a} + 1}}$ just that there are a huge number of typos in the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I've corrected the question to $a \to 0$.  Also corrected the $-1$ to $+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for all $x \neq 0$,
$$\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{a}+1} = \frac{a}{x^2+a}$$

and we have that

$$\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{a}{x^2+a} = 0$$

So

$$f(x) = 0, \forall x \neq 0.$$

However, if $x=0$

$$\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{a}{0^2 + a} = 1$$

So

$$f(0)=1.$$

Comment: Does this imply that Mathematica's simplification of ```Limit[1/(x^2/a+1),a->0]``` to $0$ is incorrect?

Comment: A lot of softwares can't handle easily expressions of this type (with limits, piecewise functions, etc, because they depend of the order of calculating the values).